# sequence of smooth functions bounded in $L^p$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

I have the following situation :

Consider $E \subset R^n$ a compact set.  Let $\Omega_1 \supset \Omega_2 \supset ... \supset \cap_i \Omega_i = E$ a sequence of bounded open sets

Supoose too $\Omega_i \supset \overline{\Omega_{i+1}}$ and $ \Omega_i \supset \overline{\cap_i \Omega_i}$.

Let $\varphi_i  \in C^{\infty}_{0} (\Omega_i)$ a sequence of functions with  $0 \leq {\varphi}_i \leq1$, $\varphi_i =1$ on $E$ and

$$\displaystyle\int_{\Omega_i} |{\varphi}_i |^p\ dx   \leq  c < \infty$$
for all i .

I need to show this :
Then $\varphi_i$ converges pointwise to a funtion $\psi$ which is $0$ in $\Omega_1 - E$ and  $1$ on E.

I am trying to use weak compactness..

Someone can give me a hint ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You must assume that the support of $\varphi_i$ is contained in $\Omega_i$ or something like that, right? But then the problem becomes easy, if I understand it right. So maybe there is a different assumption you have in mind.

Comment: $\Omega_i \supset \overline{\cap_i \Omega_i}$ is moot, since the intersection is already closed (since it's compact). Also, you probably want $\varphi_i\in C^\infty_0(\Omega_i)$.

Comment: @tomasz Not to mention $\bar E\subseteq\overline{\Omega_{i+1}}\subset\Omega_i$, (no compactness required), but yes …

Comment: To expand on my first comment: With the stated assumption on supports, the conclusion is trivial because every point outside of $E$ is outside of some $\Omega_i$. There is no need for the integral condition then. And without some further condition, the required result is trivially wrong because you can let all functions $\varphi_i$ be the same.

Comment: @Harald Hanche-Olsen .  I did a mistake, the correct is $\varphi_i \in C^{\infty}_{0} (\Omega_i)$. sorry for my mistake ..

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen, how can I define $\psi$ ?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen, how can I define $\psi$ ? a idea (using your idea )) :   a point $x$ outside of E is outside of some $\Omega_{i_0}$ then $\varphi_(i) (x) = 0$ for $i \geq i_0$. Then the limit funtion is $\psi (x) = 1, $if $x \in E$ and $\psi (x) = 0$ for $x \in \Omega_1 - E$

Comment: You nailed in your last comment. There is nothing more to it than that.